# How to clone git repository with nodegit using ssh

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, libgit2, nodegit

I'm trying to clone git repository from our teamforge server in node.js using library nodegit (version 0.2.4) and ssh.
Our server requests authentication from user and when I was trying to use only clone method without passing options I was getting error: "Callback failed to initialize SSH credentials".

I have private and public key in files private.key and public.key. They're in directory which I have set to working directory in web storm, so location shouldn't be a problem.

Didn't find example how to do it (maybe I missed it), but below code is the closest which I got:

```
'use strict';

var nodegit = require("nodegit"),
Clone = nodegit.Clone,
cred = nodegit.Cred;

var options = {
    remoteCallbacks: {
        credentials: function () {
            return cred.sshKeyNew('user', 'public.key', 'private.key', '');
        }
    }
};

Clone.clone("ssh://user@teamforgeserver.net/reponame", "localTmp", options)
  .then(function(repo) {
        var r = repo;
    },
    function(err){
        var e = err;
    }
);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isFulfilled' at value
(c:\...\proj\node_modules\nodegit\node_modules\nodegit-promise\lib\core.js:36:15)
```

Do you have hint what could be wrong or how to do it in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug with creating a new ssh key. I've created an issue [here](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/333) to track it.

In the meantime if you have an SSH agent running you can get the credentials from that.

```
'use strict';

var nodegit = require("nodegit"),
Clone = nodegit.Clone,
cred = nodegit.Cred;

var options = {
    fetchOpts: {
        remoteCallbacks: {
            credentials: function (url, userName) {
                // this is changed from sshKeyNew to sshKeyFromAgent
                return cred.sshKeyFromAgent(userName);
            }
        }
    }
};

Clone.clone("ssh://user@teamforgeserver.net/reponame", "localTmp", options)
  .then(function(repo) {
        var r = repo;
    },
    function(err){
        var e = err;
    }
);
```

That works for me in v0.2.4. If you need more realtime support feel free to come chat with us over in [our gitter channel](https://gitter.im/nodegit/nodegit).

UPDATE: I just added a fix for this on [Pull Request #334](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/pull/334). After tests pass I'll put this on master and then the code in the question should work fine.

Comment: I ran this line for line only switching out the ssh url and the directory name and got `Error: authentication required but no callback set`

Comment: There has been a change in the nodegit api. Within the option, just replace `remoteCallbacks` with `callbacks` as defined here: http://www.nodegit.org/api/fetch_options/