# We are trying to check-in file into bitbucket from nodejs/angular

Tags: bitbucket

We are trying to check-in file into bitbucket from nodejs/angular

But on ec2 we are trying to run the application we are getting error such - "Invalid request from host 192.168.1.10: Note that Bitbucket does not support Git's legacy HTTP transport protocol."

We tried using the git client such as nodegit
we getting error as "SSL certificate invalid" for clone

Any other approach available to push one file into bitbucket repository.

```js
const Git = require("nodegit");

// Clone a given repository into the `./tmp` folder.
Git.Clone("https://bitbucket.org/....", "./tmp")
  // Look up this known commit.
  .then(function(repo) {
     console.log('clone the repo');
  })
  .catch(function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Comment: you could try using ssh protocol to clone the repo. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27788121/19712974) is way to do that